# How to catch and handle org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.MissingPortletRequestParameterException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, portlet

Here is one of my controller method,

```
  @ResourceMapping(value="petPortalAction")
  @RequestMapping(params={"transactionType=BUY_PET"})
  public String handlePetPurchaseAction(
                    @RequestParam(required=true, value="petId") String petId, 
                    PortletRequest request,
                    Model model)
  {
  ... 
  }
```

As you can see, parameter petId is mandatory request parameter.
If it's missing from the request, org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.MissingPortletRequestParameterException will be raised.

My question is how to catch and handle this exception... Is there any listener in spring that I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is somewhat old, but I had the same problem (and this question comes up pretty high on Google ;-)). So here is what I did:
I added the follwing to my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="defaultExceptionHandlerTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" abstract="true">
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error/error-exception-default" />
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.MissingPortletRequestParameterException">
                error/error-missing-parameter
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultExceptionHandler" parent="defaultExceptionHandlerTemplate" />
```

The error/error-missing-parameter is the name of a view that is to be displayed. Spring will automatically publish the exception to the view, by default calling the variable "exception". On a typical JSP setup that I have the view error/error-missing-parameter maps to /WEB-INF/jsp/error/error-missing-parameter.jsp depending on your view resolver configuration. This file can for example simply look like this:

```
<jsp:root version="2.0"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="urn:jsptld:http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h1>Missing parameter</h1>
    <p>Error: The parameter '<c:out value="${exception.parameterName}" />' of type '<c:out value="${exception.parameterType}" />' is missing.</p>
</jsp:root>
```

The property "defaultErrorView" maps to a view in case that none of the exceptionMappings below matches. If you don't need this, than you can skip this property.